# Using singleton asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, singleton

I am new in programming and trying to learn singleton but stuck in somewhere.
Here is my user class:

```
public class User
{
    private static User user;

    private User() 
    {

    }

    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string isim;
    public string Isim
    {
        get { return isim; }
        set { isim = value; }
    }

    private string soyad;
    public string Soyad
    {
        get { return soyad; }
        set { soyad = value; }
    }

    public static User CreateUser() 
    {
        if (user == null)
            user = new User();
        return user;
    }
}
```

In my web form I tried this:

```
User myuser = User.CreateUser();
```

to create an object but it gives me an error like there is nothing as CreateUser()..What am I doing wrong

Comment: Nitpick: a method `CreateUser` that always returns the same user is somehow fishy

Comment: Can you post an actual exception that you are getting? I tried your code and it seems to be correct. Also since you are new I am going to say this. You can simplify the Properties on your class by doing this "public string Isim { get; private set; }"

Comment: Exact error is : 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' does not contain a definiton for 'CreateUser' and no extension method 'CreateUser' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  @P.Janowski

Comment: Isn't it correct using of singleton pattern? @TimSchmelter

Comment: @BatuhanOzdal: maybe it's just the name. If there's a method `CreateUser`  i'd expect that this method will create a new user and returns that. Instead it always returns the same (static) instance. So my expectations are completely different to the implementation which could lead to an incorrect use. If i modify that user i will modify it for all others which have used this method. One more meaningful method where a singleton pattern would make sense: `public static User GetAnonymousUser() `

Comment: I will keep this in my mind thank you :) @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is like following:

You have to modify The User class to make it like this

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Isim { get; set; }

        public string Soyad { get; set; }

        public class User(){}

        public User(int id, string isim, string soyad)
        {
            Id = id;
            Isim = isim;
            Soyad = soyad;
        }
    }
```

Then you implement Singleton (user buisiness logic) class like this

```
using System;

    public sealed class UserBusiness
    {

        private static volatile UserBusiness instance;
        private static readonly object syncRoot = new Object();

        private UserBusiness() { }

        public static UserBusiness Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    lock (syncRoot)
                    {
                        if (instance == null)
                            instance = new UserBusiness();
                    }
                }

                return instance;
            }
        }

        public void AddUser(User userToAdd)
        {
            //TODO use your ORM or whatever to acces database and add the user 
            //for example if you use entityFramework you will need to do
            //Context.Customers.Add(user)
            //Context.SaveChanges();
            //Just For Example
        }
    }
```

There are many implementation of singleton like mentioned in this MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

and finally in your webForm Code you put the following :

```
            var newUser = new User(1, "user1Isim", "user1Soyad");
            UserBusiness.Instance.AddUser(newUser);
```

After All, there are many ways to do this, depends on your needs. I found this as the simpliest way to explain.

Comment: Wow, definitely the best answer I ever get, but I think something went wrong. I add some code in UserBusiness.cs. 'MyDbName entity = new MyDbName ();'  and add AddUser method this : 'entity.PersonelTable.Add(userToAdd); entity.SaveChanges();' but I get an error on 'entity.PersonelTable.Add(userToAdd)'. Error says 'The best overloaded method match for System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SuperQquery.PersonelTable>'.Add(SuperQuery.PersonelTable)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: This is another problem, you have a problem with managing connection in Entity Framework Code First. so check this answer and post another with your code then link it here the way i can take a look at it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747614/entity-framework-cant-add-with-singleton @Karoui Haythem

Comment: @BatuhanOzdal don't forget to check both answers please