# Entity framework can't add with singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, oop, singleton

My persons class:

```
 public class User
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Isim { get; set; }

    public string Soyad { get; set; }

    public User(string isim, string soyad)
    {
        Isim = isim;
        Soyad = soyad;
    }
}
```

My UserBusiness class:

```
public sealed class UserBusiness
{
    JuqueryDbEntities entity = new JuqueryDbEntities();

    private static volatile UserBusiness instance;
    private static readonly object syncRoot = new Object();

    private UserBusiness() { }

    public static UserBusiness Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new UserBusiness();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void AddUser(User userToAdd)
    {
        entity.PersonelTable.Add(userToAdd);
        entity.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And lastly my webform codebehind onclick of a login button:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string isim = TextBox1.Text;
        string soyad = TextBox2.Text;
        var newUser = new User(isim, soyad);
        UserBusiness.Instance.AddUser(newUser);  
    }
```

Here is my problem: I get an error in AddUser method of my UserBusiness class.
An error in 'entity.PersonelTable.Add(newUser);'  line says 
'The best overload method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(SuperQquery.PersonelTable)' has some invalid arguments.' What am I doing wrong(Btw my Id is autoincrement so I am not setting it any value.)

Comment: It looks like the method `AddUser()` doesn't take an argument of type User. Have you checked what the arguments are?

Comment: I debuged it and 'userToAdd' obhect holds exact entered values so there shouldn't be a problem but I get this error @BarryO'Kane

Comment: `userToAdd` isn't the problem. Hover over the `Add` in the line `entity.PersonelTable.Add(userToAdd)` in the `UserBusiness` class, and you should see the type that the method takes. I suspect it isn't `User`.

Comment: Wow I get it now. Personel.Add takes (PersonelTable entity) as parameter but I am sending an User object. So how can I fix it. User object holds correct datas so is there a way to convert object type or something ? Any suggestions? @BarryO'Kane

Comment: @BatuhanOzdal don't forget to check both answers please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem here is that the method `Add` of `System.Data.Entity.DbSet` does simply not take argument of type user.
like mentioned in the error

> System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(SuperQquery.PersonelTable)' has some
>   invalid arguments

it takes objects of type `SuperQquery.PersonelTable`

So what you need to do is change AddUser method

```
public void AddUser(User userToAdd)
{
   SuperQquery.PersonelTable pt = new SuperQquery.PersonelTable();
   pt.FieldName1 = userToAdd.Isim;
   pt.FieldName2 = userToAdd.Soyad;

   entity.PersonelTable.Add(pt);
   entity.SaveChanges();
}
```

where FieldName are names of columns in the table of the database

EDIT: if this works, we can say that you made a conversion of type user to type SuperQquery.PersonelTable the way you can insert data in database, but the best way here is to change the class User by a new class PersonelTable with the same logic. No need to do a conversion.

Comment: It worked, I also tried the other way you mentioned and it worked too. I will use second method since you said it is a better way. Thank you

Comment: @BatuhanOzdal You have to tick the other answer of the singleton to help other people... It contains a correct answer to your question.